# Permutations and removing tuples

Tags: python, permutation

Here's my code:

```
import itertools
def permutations(string):
    if len(string) <= 1:
      return string
    return itertools.permutations(string)
```

If `'ab'` is input, it returns `[('a', 'b'), ('b', 'a')]`

Is there any way I can combine the tuple items and then change the tuple into a list item such that it returns: `['ab', 'ba']`?

Comment: Use a list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

strings are seen as iterables, and combined into tuples by `itertools.permutations`.

To convert them back as strings, just use `str.join` on the tuples (would work on a longer permutation):

```
["".join(x) for x in [('a', 'b'), ('b', 'a')]]
```

in your case:

```
["".join(x) for x in itertools.permutations(string)]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The list returned duplicates, but I added set() to remove them and it works. Thanks :)

Comment: maybe you wanted `itertools.combinations` then.

Answer (score 1):

```
 [a+b for a,b in itertools.permutations(string)]
```

Answer (score 0):

with `map`:

```
 map(lambda(x):''.join(x), itertools.permutations(string))
```